# C# - using extension methods to provide default interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I'm just learning about C# extension methods, and was wondering if I can use it to provide a default implementation for an interface.

Say:

```
public interface Animal {
    string MakeSound();
}

public static string MakeSound(this Animal) {
    return "";
}
```

Then

```
public class Dog : Animal {
    string MakeSound() {
        return "Bark";
    }
}

public class Porcupine : Animal {
}
```

And last:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
Animal porcupine = new Porcupine();

Print(dog.MakeSound());
Print(porcupine.MakeSound());
```

I'd like the porcupine and any other animals that have not explicitly implemented `MakeSound` to use the default extension method that returns an empty string, but dog and any animal that does have an explicit implementation return its own implementation such as "Bark".

So my questions:
1. Is this doable?
2. If not, is there any other way to implement default behavior for an interface?

Abstract class instead of interface is not an option because C# doesn't support multiple inheritance and my classes are inheriting behavior of another class.

Comment: No. Extension method cannot be used to satisfy interface contracts.

Comment: Ok, was worth a shot... Any other suggestions on how to do this considering I don't want to re-write the default behaviour and the fact that I can't use an abstract class?

Comment: Why don't you want an abstract class? Abstract is basically just an interface with some of the methods already implemented. Then you just override the methods for those sub-classes that need to use a different implementation to the base class.

Comment: Because there is no multiple inheritance in C#, and I need my classes to inherit another class...

Comment: Agreed, there's no multiple inheritance...but you can chain it. I.e. Class C inherits from Class B, Class B inherits from Class A.

Comment: Thats impossible because not all implementations of the interface inherit from the same base class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd generally recommend a base class, however, if that's out, you can do something like this:

```
public interface IAnimal { }

public interface INoisyAnimal : IAnimal {
    string MakeSound();
}

public static class AnimalExtensions { 
    public static string MakeSound(this IAnimal someAnimal) {
        if (someAnimal is INoisyAnimal) {
            return (someAnimal as INoisyAnimal).MakeSound();
        }
        else {
            return "Unknown Noise";
        }
    }
}

public class Dog : INoisyAnimal {
    public string MakeSound() {
        return "Bark";
    }
}

public class Porcupine : IAnimal { }
```

This makes every `IAnimal` *look* like a `INoisyAnimal` even if it isn't really one. For example:

```
IAnimal dog = new Dog();
IAnimal porcupine = new Porcupine();

Console.WriteLine(dog.MakeSound());            // bark
Console.WriteLine(porcupine.MakeSound());      // Unknown Noise
```

However, this still isn't an actual implementation of the interface. Notice that despite appearances

```
Console.WriteLine(porcupine is INoisyAnimal);  // false
```

---

Another option might be to create a wrapper to extend your base class when new functionality is needed:

```
public class NoisyAnimalWrapper : INoisyAnimal {
    private readonly IAnimal animal;
    public NoisyAnimalWrapper(IAnimal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public string MakeSound() {
        return "Unknown Noise";
    }
}

public static class AnimalExtensions { 
    public static INoisyAnimal Noisy(this IAnimal someAnimal) {
        return someAnimal as INoisyAnimal ?? 
                new NoisyAnimalWrapper(someAnimal);
    }
}
```

Then you can create a `INoisyAnimal` from any `IAnimal` whenever you need to:

```
INoisyAnimal dog = new Dog();
INoisyAnimal porcupine = new Porcupine().Noisy();

Console.WriteLine(dog.MakeSound());            // bark
Console.WriteLine(porcupine.MakeSound());      // Unknown Noise
```

You could also make the wrapper generic (e.g. `NoisyAnimal<T> where T : IAnimal, new`) and get rid of the extension method altogether. Depending on your actual use case, this may be preferable to the previous option.

Comment: I definitely agree that base class is better when applicable. About your first suggestion, since the extension methods are evaluated in compile time, won't `dog.MakeSound()` return the default behavior, even though it is an implementation of `INoisyAnimal`? Compiler doesn't know dog is of type `INoisyAnimal`, and as far as it's concerned `IAnimal.MakeSound()` extension method will be called. Am I wrong?

Comment: @tbkn23 Correct, which is why you have to a run-time check inside the extension method. Otherwise `((IAnimal)new Dog()).MakeSound()` would return `Unknown Noise`.

Comment: I agree that a base class might be much better to provide with a default behavior but keep in mind that your solution violates the Liskov substitution principle as your code is behaving differently depending on the implementation that is passed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what is your real case or if you are just experimenting but, if only some animals are noisy, then it might a good case for `Interface segregation`.

For example:

```
public class Dog : IAnimal, INoisy
{
    public string MakeSound()
    {
        return "Bark";
    }
}

public class Porcupine : IAnimal
{
}
```

Then, you will only call `MakeSound` or objects that are actually noisy.

Comment: Interface segregation can complicate wrapper design.  Given an interface with many optional methods and `canX` functions, it's easy to write a wrapper object which will be able to expose functions a wrapped object supports, without requiring that wrapped object be capable of supporting functions users of the wrapper may not need.  By contrast, given an object that implements a combination of interfaces, there's no nice way to make a wrapper implement the same combination of interfaces.

Comment: @supercat, sure thanks for your input. That made me think for a bit. Could we not try to do this without violating the L in SOLID though? I was thinking, if we have a list we could have `animals.OfType<INoisy>().ForEach(a => a.MakeSound())`.

I have seen some very horrible methods that try to understand what are the underlying implementations and they tend to grow uglier on each change.

I am curious though as what would was the real problem that the dev had been presented as it might actually had required a totally different solution than what the question suggested in the first place.

Comment: The approach I would like to see would be for a framework to allow each interface X to specify that it should be treated as being implemented by all implementations of some other interface Y, such that loading any implementations of the other interface Y that doesn't implement X will auto-generate for each member of X a member which chains to a static member of X.  Then interface `INoisyAnimal:Animal` could include property `CanMakeSound` with a default implementation that returns `false`, and function `MakeSound` with default implementation that throws an exception.

Comment: Wrapper classes would have to override those methods in order to pass them through to the wrapped objects, but a single wrapper class would be able to handle objects with a wide range of abilities without the classes of those objects having to bother with code for features that are not relevant to that class.  If default implementations were limited to being defined within the associated interface, that would avoid the Deadly Diamond (Java adds default interface implementations, but in a more general fashion which makes the Deadly Diamond possible).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? It allows you to avoid having a base class, and you can do what you had in mind, right?

```
public interface Animal
{
    // Fields
    string voice { get; }
}

public static class AnimalHelper
{
    // Called for any Animal
    public static string MakeSound(this Animal animal)
    {
        // Common code for all of them, value based on their voice
        return animal.voice;
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string voice { get { return "Woof!"; } }
}

public class Purcupine : Animal
{
    public string voice { get { return ""; } }
}
```